# form javascript. display it in html file

Tags: javascript, html

MY HTML AND JAVASCRIPT

```
<html>
    <script type= "text/javascript">
    function registerform(){
        var fullnameExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
            var fullname= document.getElementById('fullname');  
        if(fullname.value.match(fullnameExp)){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert("Error!");
            return false;

        }
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <form>
    <input type='text' id='fullname' size="50"/>
    <button onClick="registerform()">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <body>
    </html>
```

How do i make the Alert change to document.write and shows it next to form box. If only theres error.

Comment: What is it doing at the moment?

Comment: Why do you want to use `document.write`? Are you just trying to display the error?

Comment: now if theres error it will Alert it. i want to make it display next to the form box. if it meets the else criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use `document.write`

```
<html>
    <script type= "text/javascript">
    function registerform(){
        var fullnameExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
            var fullname= document.getElementById('fullname');  
        if(fullname.value.match(fullnameExp)){
            return true;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("err").innerHTML="error";
            return false;

        }
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <form>
    <input type='text' id='fullname' size="50"/>
    <button onClick="registerform()">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <span id="err"></span>
    <body>
    </html>
```

Comment: yeah it works but why does the error show for like a brief amount of time. like less than half a second